# DatePicker not able to go away from current month and year

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im using the DatePickerField like this for inputting DOB

```
           <DatePickerField
              name={dateOfBirth.name}
              label={dateOfBirth.label}
              format="dd/mm/yy"
              views={['date', 'month', 'year']}
              minDate={new Date('31/12/1900')}
              maxDate={new Date()}
              fullWidth
            />
```

Here is the code for DatePickerField.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useField } from 'formik';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from '@material-ui/pickers';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';

export default function DatePickerField(props) {
  const [field, meta, helper] = useField(props);
  const { touched, error } = meta;
  const { setValue } = helper;
  const isError = touched && error && true;
  const { value } = field;
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value) {
      const date = new Date(value);
      setSelectedDate(date);
    }
  }, [value]);

  function _onChange(date) {
    if (date) {
      setSelectedDate(date);
      try {
        const ISODateString = date.toISOString();
        setValue(ISODateString);
      } catch (error) {
        setValue(date);
      }
    } else {
      setValue(date);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          {...field}
          {...props}
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={_onChange}
          error={isError}
          invalidDateMessage={isError && error}
          helperText={isError && error}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

I'm unable to navigate to any month or Year using this. I have defined `minDate` too. Not sure what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
views={['year', 'month', 'date']}
minDate={new Date('1900/12/01')}
```